# How does one add annonation on a Google Scatter Plot?

Tags: google-sheets

I can do it in a area chart, but for the life of me it can't get it to work on a scatter plot. Is it at all possible? Google's tutorial is incredibly short and mysterious: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2382813?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End of the first paragraph in your link:

> They’re currently available for line and area charts only.